# jq | get the paths value after filtered paths

Tags: json, path, jq

Let's say I have the following JSON:

```json
{
  "A": {
    "ID": "something"
  },
  "B": {
    "ID": "something-else"
  },
  "C": {
    "ID": "something"
  },
  "D": {
    "E": {
      "ID": "something"
    }
  }
}
```

and I want to get all the paths that contain `"ID": "something"`:

```
A.ID
C.ID
D.E.ID
```

to try to do it I'm using this to get all the paths that have the `ID` key

```
paths | select(.[-1] == "ID")
```

but the output is:

```json
[ "A", "ID" ]
[ "B", "ID" ]
[ "C", "ID" ]
[ "D", "E", "ID" ]
```

[jq playground](https://jqplay.org/s/hNhnpukEhv-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible to do with `getpath/1`. Collect the paths matching your condition and extract the value at each path to see if matches your condition

```
( paths | select(.[-1] == "ID")) as $p | 
  if getpath($p) == "something" then ( $p | join(".") ) else empty end
```

[jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/nQOuJuLtEWs)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be using the `--stream` option (or the `tostream` function), and check both criteria at once:

```bash
jq -r --stream 'select(.[0][-1] == "ID" and .[1] == "something")[0] | join(".")'
```

```
A.ID
C.ID
D.E.ID
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/c6MyOJ1Oc30)

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution is a script I've written called [`jqg`](https://github.com/NorthboundTrain/jqg/) that will flatten the JSON and then search through it. It's not a perfect fit because it cannot search both the keys for one string and the values for another in a single invocation, but that's easily accomplished by stringing together two invocations with a pipe (`|`). On the plus side, you don't have to rewrite it every time your search criteria changes.

`/tmp/so72977106.json` - sample JSON with a bunch of extra edge cases thrown in

```json
{
  "A": {
    "ID": "something"
  },
  "B": {
    "ID": "something-else"
  },
  "C": {
    "ID": "something"
  },
  "C2": {
    "ID": {
      "name": "something"
    }
  },
  "C3": {
    "name": "ID"
  },
  "C4": {
    "XID": "something"
  },
  "C5": {
    "ID": "not-something"
  },
  "D": {
    "E": {
      "ID": "something"
    }
  }
}
```

```
$ jqg -k '\.ID$' /tmp/so72977106.json | jqg -vKr ^something$
A.ID
C.ID
D.E.ID
```

The first invocation searches just the keys (`-k`) for the regex `\.ID$` and the second invocation searches just the values (`-v`) for the regex `^something$`. The output of the second invocation is modified to print out just the raw (`-r`), flattened keys (`-K`); otherwise it would produce valid JSON, e.g. the output of just the first invocation:

```
$ jqg -k '\.ID$' /tmp/so72977106.json
{
  "A.ID": "something",
  "B.ID": "something-else",
  "C.ID": "something",
  "C5.ID": "not-something",
  "D.E.ID": "something"
}
```

NOTE: I am the author of this script.